# increments returning different binary search result

Tags: javascript, typescript, binary-search

Created a simple binary search and I noticed that the usage of `mid--` vs `mid -= 1` or `mid - 1` returned different results and essentially caused the function to fail. I was scanning resources online and based on reading other SO posts, my assumption is that the `--` and `++` operators are able to change the value of `mid` for each iteration ... but it seems so nuanced that I'm not really tracking what's going on behind the scenes. Would appreciate some help regarding this.

I would think that both `mid -= 1` and `mid--` mean take `mid` and reduce its value by one. Both essentially reassigning the -1 value to the `mid` variable.

#### works

```js
const sourceArray = [1, 5, 7, 10, 15];

const binarySearch = (array, target) => {
  let low = 0;
  let high = array.length - 1;

  while (low < high) {
    let mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (array[mid] === target) {
      return mid;
    } else if (array[mid] > target) {
      // if array[mid] > target, set high to mid--
      high = mid--;
    } else {
      // if array[mid] < target, set low to mid++
      low = mid++;
    }
  }
  return [];
};

console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 7));
console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 10));
console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 15));
console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 20));

// returns
// 2
// 3
// 4
// []
```

#### doesnt work

```js
const sourceArray = [1, 5, 7, 10, 15];

const binarySearch = (array, target) => {
  let low = 0;
  let high = array.length - 1;

  while (low < high) {
    let mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (array[mid] === target) {
      return mid;
    } else if (array[mid] > target) {
      // if array[mid] > target, set high to mid--
      high = mid -= 1;
    } else {
      // if array[mid] < target, set low to mid++
      low = mid += 1;
    }
  }
  return [];
};

console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 7));
console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 10));
console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 15));
console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 20));

// returns
// 2
// []
// []
// []
```

Answer (score 0):

The post-decrement operator (`--`) returns the value, then decrements it, so if `mid` is 3, your line:

```
high = mid--;
```

Sets `high` to 3 and then decrements `mid` by 1, leaving 2 in `mid`.

In your second example, you have two assignments on the same line:

```
high = mid -= 1;
```

Let's use the example of `mid` with a value of 3 again. Multiple assignments in a single statement work right-to-left. First, you are subtracting 1 from `mid` and storing the value 2 in `mid`. Then, you are assigning that 2 to `high`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `while` condition should be `low <= high`. Consider having an array of a single element, that won't enter the loop at all.

Secondly, you should use `Math.floor((low + high) / 2);` instead. Consider `low` and `high` having a different parity. Clearly, mid will be a fractional value. For example, you will access `sourceArray[2.5]` which is undefined.

Finally, you should use the prefix increment and decrement because they return their value after incrementing and decrementing i.e `--mid` and `++mid`

The modifications I made in your code:

```
const sourceArray = [1, 5, 7, 10, 15];

const binarySearch = (array, target) => {
  let low = 0;
  let high = array.length - 1;

  while (low <= high) {
    let mid = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    if (array[mid] === target) {
      return mid;
    } else if (array[mid] > target) {
      // if array[mid] > target, set high to mid - 1
      high = --mid;
    } else {
      // if array[mid] < target, set low to mid + 1
      low = ++mid;
    }
  }
  return [];
};

console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 7));
console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 10));
console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 15));
console.log(binarySearch(sourceArray, 20));
```